# trim() method do not remove white spaces in front of the text?

Tags: java, string, trim, hashset, stringbuffer

Please have a look at the below code

```
while (reader.hasNext()) 
          {
          JsonParser  _parser = new JsonParser();
          JsonElement jsonElement =  _parser.parse(reader);
          JsonObject jsonObject1 = jsonElement.getAsJsonObject();

              int totalNumberOfUniqueWords=0;

          //Add Title and Body Together to the list
          String titleAndBodyContainer = " My Name is something that you don't know. you know that anyway? My Name?";

              //Remove full stops and commas
              titleAndBodyContainer.trim();
          titleAndBodyContainer = titleAndBodyContainer.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z'\\s]+", " ");
          titleAndBodyContainer = titleAndBodyContainer.toLowerCase();
              titleAndBodyContainer.trim();

              StringBuffer wordList = new StringBuffer("");

              //Removing Duplicate Words
              HashSet<String>noDup = new HashSet<String>();
              String[]titleAndBodyContainerArray = titleAndBodyContainer.split(" ");

              for(int i=0;i<titleAndBodyContainerArray.length;i++)
              {
                  if(!noDup.contains(titleAndBodyContainerArray[i].trim()))
                  {
                      wordList.append(titleAndBodyContainerArray[i].trim());
                      wordList.append(";");
                      noDup.add(titleAndBodyContainerArray[i].trim());
                      break;
                  }
              }

              System.out.println(wordList.toString());
              break;


              //index++;
          }
```

In all the time, the output is `;`. This simply means white space in front of the sentence is not removed! There is no output if I replace the `titleAndBodyContainer` to be `"My Name is something that you don't know. you know that anyway? My Name?"`, because it has no white space in front of the sentence. What is wrong here?

Comment: The only output you get is a single `;` seems like something isn't working outside of `trim`. Make sure you know what titleAndBodyContainer is after each step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`titleAndBodyContainer.trim()` does not trim the original string, but returns a trimmed version of it.

Try

```
String trimmedTitleAndBodyContainer = titleAndBodyContainer.trim();
```

then process the result.